# tcl_findLibrary doesn't work

Tags: compilation, tcl, tk-toolkit, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to run freshly compiled program, written with Tcl&Tk. When running it I get an error:

```bash
felix@Astroserver:~/Документы/Simon$ sudo ./simon1
invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, I have installed Tcl&Tk (cause I was able to succesfully build the program).

If I'm running *wish*:

```tcl
% tcl_findLibrary
wrong # args: should be "tcl_findLibrary basename version patch initScript enVarName varName"
```

Could anyone help?

```c
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    int main_window;

    char *args;
    char buf[20];   /* intermediate storage to pass a value to TCL */
    char *tcl_command;  /* points to a string of a TCL command line */
    int tcl_return_value;/* is either TCL_OK or TCL_ERROR */

    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    /* Command line arguments are passed to TCL. TCL stores in argv0 the name
    of the command, that is argv[0], in argv all other arguments, and in
    argc the number of arguments. */

    args = Tcl_Merge(argc - 1, argv+1);
    Tcl_SetVar(interp, "argv", args, TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
    ckfree(args); /* Tcl_Merge allocates memory for the returned string */

    sprintf(buf, "%d", argc - 1);
    Tcl_SetVar(interp, "argc", buf, TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);

    Tcl_SetVar(interp, "argv0", argv[0], TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);

    /* Create main window and do some initialization for Tcl/Tk */
    main_window = Tk_Init(interp);
    if (main_window != TCL_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", interp->result);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (Tcl_AppInit(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        printf("%s\n",interp->result);
        exit(1);
    }


    /* testing if environment variable SIMON_PATH is specified */
    tcl_return_value = Tcl_Eval(interp, 
            "if {![info exist env(SIMON_PATH)]} {"
            "puts \"Environment variable SIMON_PATH is missing!\";"
            "exit }");

    /* Evaluate my GUI simon.tk */

    /* the 33 is the lenght of the string "source $env(SIMON_PATH)/simon.tk" */
    tcl_command = (char *)MyMalloc(33 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tcl_command,"source $env(SIMON_PATH)/simon.tk");

    tcl_return_value = Tcl_Eval(interp, tcl_command);
    if (*interp->result != 0) printf("%s \n", interp->result);
    if (tcl_return_value != TCL_OK)
    {
        printf("simon.tk at line: %d\n",interp->errorLine);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Waiting for interactive events. */

    Tk_MainLoop();
}

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{  
    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
}
    if (Tk_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
}
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_parser", SET_Parser, (ClientData) NULL,
        (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_c2tcl_data", SET_C2TclData,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);

    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_free_and_reset_module_data", 
        SET_FreeAndResetModuleData,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_free_and_reset_global_data", 
        SET_FreeAndResetGlobalData,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_reset_sim_control_parameter", 
        SET_ResetSimControlParameter,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_random_number", SET_RandomNumber,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_scale_graph_data", SET_ScaleGraphData,
        (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to initialize the Tcl interpreter?

Comment: Side note: you can safely pass a constant string to `Tcl_Eval` these days. (I can't remember offhand if this is true in 8.4, but it's definitely true in 8.5.) This means you don't need to mess around with copying the string into writable memory first; simplifies things!

Comment: This program is reeealy old :) 1995 or smth like this. I finaly started it - main_window = Tk_Init(interp); shouldn't be there, baceause it was tcl_CreateMainWindow command and I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Tcl_CreateInterp` instead of `Tcl_Main`, which is OK but *requires* that you call `Tcl_FindExecutable` first (to initialize the library). The first call into Tcl's C interface must always be either `Tcl_FindExecutable` or `Tcl_Main` (because that calls `Tcl_FindExecutable` for you). When Tcl isn't initialized, all sorts of odd things can go wrong; we don't warrant the correct operation of the code in that case.

Having seen your code, I'd recommend switching to using `Tk_Main` (like `Tcl_Main`, but Tk-enabled). You'd end up with code like this:

```c
static int AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    /* Basic init */
    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    if (Tk_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "Tk", Tk_Init, Tk_SafeInit);
    /* Make your commands here */
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_parser",           SET_Parser, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_c2tcl_data",       SET_C2TclData, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_random_number",    SET_RandomNumber, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_scale_graph_data", SET_ScaleGraphData, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_free_and_reset_module_data", 
            SET_FreeAndResetModuleData, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_free_and_reset_global_data", 
            SET_FreeAndResetGlobalData, NULL, NULL);
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "set_reset_sim_control_parameter", 
            SET_ResetSimControlParameter, NULL, NULL);
    /* Can't remember if you need this */
    Tcl_SetVar(interp, "tcl_rcFileName", "~/.simonrc", TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
    /* Now your remaining initialization - assume no error for this! */
    Tcl_Eval(interp, 
            "if {![info exist env(SIMON_PATH)]} {"
            "puts \"Environment variable SIMON_PATH is missing!\";"
            "exit }");
    /* Read your startup code */
    return Tcl_Eval(interp, "source $env(SIMON_PATH)/simon.tk");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tk_Main(argc, argv, AppInit);
    return 0; /* Not Reached */
}
```